# Set New SQL Column Value Based on Date

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a new column in my database table that already has 500k records of users, this new column value should either be A or B alternatively, suppose I have 5 users in my table:

| User | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | Null |
| User 2 | Null |
| User 3 | Null |
| User 4 | Null |
| User 5 | Null |

User 5 being the last user registered and user 1 the first, I have a registration date column, what I want is to assign the value like this:

| User | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| User 1 | B |
| User 2 | A |
| User 3 | B |
| User 4 | A |
| User 5 | B |

How can I do this with an SQL script or using entity framework co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may update the `New Column` value using a CTE as the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *,
   CASE 
     WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User]) % 2 = 1 
     THEN 'B' 
     ELSE 'A'
   END AS AB_Value
  FROM table_name
)
UPDATE CTE SET NewColumn = AB_Value;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z5KCshOV) on SQL Server.